# Question about Lagrangian Multiplier (Gradient) Statistic of constrained GMM

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, estimation, econometrics, generalized-moments

I am trying to derive the Lagrangian multiplier statistic (GMM version) under a restriction. The question is given below

The quadratic form is given by $Q_n(\theta,\alpha)=[m(\theta)', (m^a(\theta)-\alpha)']\begin{pmatrix}
   W_{11} & W_{12} \\
   W_{21} & W_{22} \\
     \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    m(\theta)\\
    m^a(\theta)-\alpha\\ 
     \end{pmatrix},$ where $\theta, \alpha$ are vectors.

Now they ask to verify that the Lagrangian Multiplier (Gradient) Statistic for testing the null hypothesis $H_0: \alpha=0,$ based on the moment condition \begin{pmatrix}
    m(\theta)\\
    m^a(\theta)-\alpha\\ 
     \end{pmatrix}can be expressed as $$n(m(\tilde{\theta})', m^a(\tilde{\theta})'){W_n}^{-1}S{\tilde{V}}^{-1}S'{W_n}^{-1}  \begin{pmatrix}
    m(\tilde{\theta} )\\
    m^a(\tilde{\theta})-\alpha\\ 
     \end{pmatrix},$$where \tilde{\theta} is the restricted estimate of $\theta$, ${W_n}$ is a consistent estimate of $\bar{\Sigma}$, $S'=[0,I]$, and $$\tilde{V}=S'W^{-1}_nS-S'W^{-1}_n\tilde{D}(\tilde{D}'W^{-1}_n\tilde{D})^{-1}\tilde{D}'W^{-1}_nS$$with
$\tilde{D}'=[\partial m(\tilde{\theta})'/\partial \theta, \partial m^a(\tilde{\theta})'/\partial \theta ].$

My attempt is:

Now we can rewrite the $H_0:\alpha=0$ as $S[\theta,\alpha]=0.$ To minimize $Q_n(\theta,\alpha)$ subject to $H_0$ we set up Lagrangian $L=G_n(\theta,\alpha)-2\lambda'S[\theta,\alpha].$ The first order conditions are $\begin{pmatrix}
   \partial m(\theta)'/\partial \theta & \partial m^a(\theta)'/\partial \theta   \\
    0 & -I \\
     \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
   W_{11} & W_{12} \\
   W_{21} & W_{22} \\
     \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    m(\theta)\\
    m^a(\theta)-\alpha\\ 
     \end{pmatrix} = S\lambda$ and $\alpha =0$. Solving this simultaneously we can get  the foc
$\begin{pmatrix}
    \tilde{D}'         \\
     -S'                 \\ 
     \end{pmatrix}W^{-1}_n\begin{pmatrix}
    m(\tilde{\theta})\\
    m^a(\tilde{\theta})\\ 
     \end{pmatrix} =S\tilde{\lambda}.
$

Now impose this into the form of Lagrangian statistic, we get $TLM =n{\tilde{\lambda}}'S'[\begin{pmatrix}
    \tilde{D}'         \\
     -S'                 \\ 
     \end{pmatrix}W^{-1}_n\begin{pmatrix}
    \tilde{D}'         \\
     -S'                 \\ 
     \end{pmatrix}]^{-1}S\tilde{\lambda}. $ If we replace $S\tilde{\lambda}$ by $\begin{pmatrix}
    \tilde{D}'         \\
     -S'                 \\ 
     \end{pmatrix}W^{-1}_n
\begin{pmatrix}
    m(\tilde{\theta})\\
    m^a(\tilde{\theta})\\ 
     \end{pmatrix}$, then it suffices to show that $\begin{pmatrix}
    \tilde{D}'         \\
     -S'                 \\ 
     \end{pmatrix}[\begin{pmatrix}
    \tilde{D}'         \\
     -S'                 \\ 
     \end{pmatrix}W^{-1}_n\begin{pmatrix}
    \tilde{D}'         \\
     -S'                 \\ 
     \end{pmatrix}]^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}
    \tilde{D}'         \\
     -S'                 \\ 
     \end{pmatrix}=S{\tilde{V}}^{-1}S'$. I calculated that $\begin{pmatrix}
    \tilde{D}'         \\
     -S'                 \\ 
     \end{pmatrix}W^{-1}_n\begin{pmatrix}
    \tilde{D}'         \\
     -S'                 \\ 
     \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
   S'W^{-1}_nS & \tilde{D}'W^{-1}_nS \\
   S'W^{-1}_n\tilde{D} & \tilde{D}'W^{-1}_n\tilde{D} \\
     \end{pmatrix}$.

I tried to get the inverse of the above square matrix and multiplied by both sides. However, couldn't get the required form. I am wondering if my constrained GMM estimate is wrong, and the foc is incorrect. Or maybe there is something that I missed out. Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance.